# Find moved object in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

For example, I have sorted array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. And after user moving some element, as example here it's 6, I have an array [1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5]. How to find out which element was moved. I need it index.

A simple enumeration with checking for equality of each pair of elements is my inefficient solution.

Comment: What is `moving operation`? It is worth to define it clearly.

Comment: Why do you think your solution is inefficient?

Comment: When we have [1,3,2,4,5,6], then which do you consider the element that was moved? 2 or 3? Please show your code and what the efficiency problem is you have.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the worst case complexity cannot be less than O(n) here. Consider finding two elements swapped

Comment: For the special case of an integer array consisting of consecutive integers a binary search approach would probably work. For more arbitrary sorted lists I think that @Marat is right that you won't do any better than linear.

Comment: Create two array
ActualArray
ChangedArray
Now check where actual array is not equal to changed array... Simply 

Comment: The best you're going to do is a linear search from the beginning to find the first change, and a linear search from the end to find the first change. For example, consider an array that starts as 123456789, and after the move is 123745689. Searching from the beginning, the first change is from 4 to 7. Searching from the end, the first change is 7 to 6. Since 7 is the number common to both changes, the 7 was moved.

Comment: The problem gets harder if duplicates are allowed in the array. Consider an array that starts as 33335555, and after the move is 33533555. Searching from the beginning, the first change is from 3 to 5. Searching from the end, the first change is 5 to 3. It's obvious to a human that the 5 was moved, but even a human can't say which 5 was moved. The computer, knowing only that 3 changed to 5 and 5 changed to 3, can't say which was moved, and has to do additional work to find the answer.

Comment: @user3386109 I've already implemented that solution, before noticed your answer. So thanks anyway. And no, there are only unique numbers, without duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

@user3386109 describes the solution very well in the comments. I just want to show you my code sample.

```
let oldOrderArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let newOrderArray = [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6];
let movedItem = 0;
let mismatchPoint = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < newOrderArray.length; i++) {
    if (oldOrderArray[i] != newOrderArray[i]) {
        mismatchPoint = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (newOrderArray[mismatchPoint] > newOrderArray[mismatchPoint + 1]) {
    movedItem = newOrderArray[mismatchPoint];
} else {
    for (let i = newRateOrder.length; i > mismatchPoint; i--) {
        if (oldOrderArray[i] != newOrderArray[i]) {
            movedItem = newOrderArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```